# how to list file names when searching for strings passed by cat with pipe

Tags: command-line, grep, pipe

I want to search for a string in the files in a directory like:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/*  | grep  pam_ck_connector.so
```

but I also want to list the file names in which files the string `pam_ck_connector.so` found. `grep -l` switch is apparently for that purpose but it fails in this case:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/*  | grep -l pam_ck_connector.so

(standard input)
```

What is the correct algorithm to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4):

This is a canonical [Useless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Use `grep` directly:

```
grep -R pam_ck_connector.so /etc/pam.d/
```

With the `-R` flag, it will recursively search the directory. If, for some reason, you don't want to search subdirectories and only want to print filenames, then do:

```
grep -l pam_ck_connector.so /etc/pam.d/*
```

The `-l` flag is for printing only the filenames.